How to disable opentelemetry tracer exporter in hono?
SEVERE [io.ope.exp.int.grp.OkHttpGrpcExporter] (OkHttp http://localhost:4317/...) Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Full error message: Failed to connect to localhost:4317

Getting above error for hono services which are running on docker-swarm. I want to disable opentelemetry tracer exporter for Hono, how can I achieve it?
Here are my configurations:
quarkus:
  log:
    min-level: TRACE
    level: INFO
    category:
      "io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime":
        level: DEBUG
  opentelemetry:
    tracer:
      exporter:
        otlp: 
          enabled: false

I also tried below options, but still getting same error:
quarkus.otel.traces.exporter=none
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter=none
quarkus.otel.enabled= false
quarkus.opentelemetry.tracer.exporter.oltp=none

Setting quarkus.otel.sdk.disabled=true has helped me to disable opentelemetry tracer exporter.
quarkus:
  log:
    min-level: TRACE
    level: INFO
    category:
      "io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime":
        level: DEBUG
  otel:
    sdk:
      disabled: true

